I have some questions about heat transfer (heat evaporative minichannel heat sink)
Problem Description
As shown in the diagram, an evaporative minichannel heat sink with 48 minichannels is being analyzed. A glass plate is attached to the top of the minichannels for flow visualization, and water is supplied as the working fluid at a mass flux of 410 kg/m²·s. A uniform heat flux of 100 W/cm² is applied at the bottom of the minichannels. The inlet temperature of the water is 50°C, and the pressure is 17.5 kPa, assuming no pressure drop. Each minichannel has a length of 25.4 mm, width of 1 mm, and height of 1 mm.

Tasks
Determine the boiling location thermodynamically in the minichannels and calculate the quality (x) of the fluid at the outlet.
Although it is a flow boiling scenario, calculate the convective heat transfer coefficient at the boiling location in the minichannel using appropriate assumptions.
According to Qu and Mudawar's (2004) CHF correlation, calculate the critical heat flux in the minichannels. The CHF correlation is as follows:
: maximum critical heat flux applied to the bottom of the minichannel.
Assess whether burning out occurs due to CHF and discuss whether design changes are necessary for the minichannel configuration.


